# What happens differently in puppeteer with a browser.close() vs simply terminating the whole program?

Tags: node.js, chromium, puppeteer

I have a site that in order to test, I first login. I then perform multiple tasks and then issue a browser.close().

But I have found that if I simply terminate the whole node program, upon reopening the same page again, the login persists and it doesn't require logging in again. (when testing in non-headless mode, I also notice that it says 'chrome has recovered from a crash'.

However, if I use browser.close() and terminate the node program or even re-launch again and navigate again to the same page, login IS required. In other words, chromium is retaining something upon crashing that it doesn't when issuing a browser.close().

I am saving the userDataDir in both cases. So I was hoping to be fully saving all cookies and other data in either case.

My preferred outcome would be to fully save state so that logging in is not required as often.

However, the documentation says that browser.close() terminates the chromium process. My node script is written to handle lots of different browser processes simultaneously. So things would become memory constrained rather quickly if I simply did a browser.disconnect() when done on every process.

Any ideas how I can more perfectly 'freeze' state on a browsing session so that we can pick it back up later?

Comment: I'm confused--sounds like the login isn't required either way? Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: @ggorlen This question was from 3 years ago, but it looks like I had a typo. (maybe that is why no one answered it :) I made the correction. When using browser.close() the website DID in fact require me to login again, where a browser crash would NOT require a new login. Looking back, my guess is that the browser.close() provides some kind of notification to the website in question and the website is being overly cautious and invalidating credentials when the user closes the browser. So it might be handy if puppeteer has an option to close without notifying the website.

Comment: more like `browser.close()` properly wipes any session cookies while crashing the browser dont give time to do that. its very similar to how browser can restore previous session after you kill its processes using external means (e.g. task manager on windows, `kill` on *nixes, power outtage, etc).